# I can't show the value of aaData for total, using datatable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I've a problem when access to value for `aaData` in "fnFooterCallback".

This is the output of log:

> aaData: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Really, I've 4 rows to show in datatable, but I can't access these values to show totals in dataset.

I try to use this:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
     console.log("aaData: "+oSettings.aoData ); 
     iTotal = [0, 0];
     for (var i = 0; i < oSettings.aoData.length; i++) {
         iTotal[0] += oSettings.aoData[i]._aData.quantity;
     }

    //Totales
     $("#Totales").empty();
     $("#Totales").append('<th>sum</th><th>'+iTotal[0]+'</th>');
}
```

i also try with this:

```
"fnFooterCallback" : function(nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
    console.log("aaData: " + aaData);
    var totalCantidad = 0;
    for ( var i = 0; i < aaData.length; i++) {
        totalCantidad = totalCantidad+ parseInt(aaData[i].Cantidad) * 1;
    }
    var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
    nCells[1].innerHTML = totalCantidad;
}
```

This is my definition for the datatable:

```
$("#lineOutletTable").dataTable({
    "bInfo" : false,
    "bPaginate" : false,
    "bLengthChange" : true,
    "iDisplayLength" : -1,
    "bFilter" : false,
    "bSort" : true,
    "aaSorting" : [ [ 0, "asc" ] ],
    "bAutoWidth" : false,
    "oLanguage" : spanishInfo,
    "aoColumns" : columnsTableLine,
    "sPaginationType" : "bootstrap",
    "iDisplayStart" : 20,
    "sScrollY" : "60px",
    "sDom" : "<row-fluid'<'span6 wrapMedidasReales'><'span6 wrapPrecios'>>t<row-fluid'<'span6 'l><'span6'p>>",
    "fnDrawCallback" : function(oSettings) {
        console.log("aaData: " + oSettings.aoData);
        iTotal = [ 0, 0 ];
        for ( var i = 0; i < oSettings.aoData.length; i++) {
            iTotal[0] += oSettings.aoData[i]._aData.quantity;
        }
        // Totales
        $("#Totales").empty();
        $("#Totales").append('<th>sum</th><th>' + iTotal[0] + '</th>');
    },
    "fnFooterCallback" : function(nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
        console.log("aaData: " + aaData);
        var totalCantidad = 0;
        for ( var i = 0; i < aaData.length; i++) {
            totalCantidad = totalCantidad + parseInt(aaData[i].Cantidad) * 1;
        }
        var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
        nCells[1].innerHTML = totalCantidad;
    }
});
```

I read the values from `Ajax`, the dataset work correctly except the totals.

How I can access to values in aaData?

Comment: Try: iTotal[0] += parseint(oSettings.aoData[i]._aData.quantity);

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understan what you want to do exactly, since you didn't include the html part of your table and the result from the ajax call. So I don't know where you want to display your totals.

Have a look at this code:

```
$(function() {
  totals = 0;
  var otable = $("#datatable").dataTable({
    "fnFooterCallback": function(nRow, aaData, iStart,
      iEnd, aiDisplay) {
      x = aaData;
      $.each(x, function(key, value) {
        totals = totals + parseInt(value[1]);
      })
      $("#Totales").empty();
      $("#Totales").append('Totals: ' + totals);

    }
  });
});
```

and this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RgdeY5qmGuAg2RZbiLvp?p=preview)

This should at least give you a hint abot how to access the aaData. Maybe use the plunker as base and fill in your completed deffinitions. Then we have a better starting point.

Answer (score 0):

the code for Html is:

```
<div class="row finder-line-outlet-container table-wrapper">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
                    class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed dataTable customTable"
                    id="lineOutletTable" aria-describedby="example_info">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Totales</th>
                            <th id="totalCantidad"></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th id="totalMetros"></th>
                            <th></th>   
                            <th></th>                           
                        </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

i use your function, but the error is the same, when i print in console the value of totals is NaN .

I access to data with ajax.

I solve the problem , in the function Ajax, that bring data, i sum the values, and in fnFooterCallback, print the values, but, why don't work, when sum the values in fnFooterCallback?

Comment: If you get a NaN Error (Not a Number) it is probably related to summing up values that are not a number, like strings. Although they might look like normal numbers they are in fact not. Thats what parseint() is for. It converts a string to a number which can be handled by mathematical operations. Again: it would be more helpfull if you show us the data you get from your ajax call. And plz: Don't post extensions to your question as an answer that does not work and has no value to others that want to learn how to solve an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this then:

```
console.log("aaData: "+oSettings.aoData.length);
```

Should work fine, if I got your question right..